# multivariate forecasting using sktime

Tags: time-series, forecasting, sktime

I am new to sktime and time series forecasting. I am using the following Kaggle dataset to forecast sales for different stores:

[image]

I have created x_train and y_train datasets as follows:

[image] [image]

I want to train a model using date, store, and item features and make predictions. **I am now looking for an example**, where I can use SkTime to train **Arima, Prophet, and LightGBM** model on the x_train dataset. After training, I will like to make predictions using x_test dataset.

**x_test** dataset has the same structure as **x_train** i.e. having date, store, and item columns.

Any help or guidance will be really appreciated.

Thank